# Loop & Search for Matching Worksheets in Separate Wkbks; Add Wksht if No Match Found

Tags: vba, excel

I have a series of workbooks by District, Territory, and Period that have monthly sales data for each combination of District, Territory, and Period. There is a master workbook for each District containing separate worksheets for each Territory. The monthly data appears in columns `B:M`.

I need to open each of the monthly District, Territory, and Period files, open the corresponding District's master workbook, search for a corresponding Territory, and paste that month's data in the column associated with that month (e.g., Feb. data is pasted in column C). This should be followed by closing the monthly file and loop to the next monthly file.

However, I need to have code for the possibility that a NEW Territory is added to a District in midyear--sometime after that District's master workbook was initially created.

The loop as written wants to jump from the open monthly file to the next part of the loop code that would create a new worksheet, but that is not what is needed.

Any suggestions for fixing this?  Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub DSMReportsP02()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim DistrictDSM As Range, DistrictsDSMList As Range
    Dim Period As String, Path As String, DistPeriodFile As String, Territory As String
    Dim YYYY As Variant
    Dim WBMaster As Workbook, DistMaster As Workbook, CurDstTerrFile As Workbook
    Dim wsCount As Integer, x As Integer
    Dim wsExists As Boolean

    Set DistrictsDSMList = Range("E11:E" & Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)
    Set WBMaster = ActiveWorkbook
    Period = Range("C6").Value
    YYYY = Range("C8").Value
    wsExists = False

    For Each DistrictDSM In DistrictsDSMList.Cells

        Workbooks.Open Filename:="H:\Accounting\Monthend " & YYYY & "\DSM Files\DSM Master Reports\" & DistrictDSM & ".xlsx"
        Set DistMaster = ActiveWorkbook
        wsCount = Application.Sheets.Count

        Path = "H:\Accounting\Monthend " & YYYY & "\DSM Files\" & DistrictDSM & "\P02"
        DistPeriodFile = Dir(Path & "\*.xlsx")

        Do While DistPeriodFile <> ""

            Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & "\" & DistPeriodFile, UpdateLinks:=False
            DistPeriodFile = Dir
            Set CurDstTerrFile = ActiveWorkbook
            Territory = CurDstTerrFile.Sheets("Index").Range("A3").Value

            For x = 1 To wsCount
                If DistMaster.Worksheets(x).name = Territory Then
                    CurDstTerrFile.Sheets("Index").Range("F20").Copy 'PM
                    DistMaster.Sheets(Territory).Activate
                    Range("C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                    CurDstTerrFile.Sheets("Index").Range("J20").Copy 'XRA
                    DistMaster.Sheets(Territory).Activate
                    Range("C5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                    CurDstTerrFile.Sheets("Index").Range("N20").Copy 'CO-OP
                    DistMaster.Sheets(Territory).Activate
                    Range("C7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                    CurDstTerrFile.Sheets("Index").Range("S20").Copy 'VR
                    DistMaster.Sheets(Territory).Activate
                    Range("C9").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                    CurDstTerrFile.Sheets("Index").Range("W20").Copy 'OVER & ABOVE
                    DistMaster.Sheets(Territory).Activate
                    Range("C11").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                    CurDstTerrFile.Sheets("Index").Range("AA20").Copy 'SS
                    DistMaster.Sheets(Territory).Activate
                    Range("C13").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                    CurDstTerrFile.Sheets("Index").Range("A3:D19").Copy 'COPY BTs by DISTRICT
                    WBMaster.Sheets("BTs by District").Activate
                    Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

                    Exit For
                End If
            Next x

            If wsExists = False Then             '***********FIX THIS SECTION!!!*************************
                Worksheets.Add after:=DistMaster.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

                CurDstTerrFile.Sheets("Index").Range("A3").Copy 'COPY TERRITORY
                ActiveSheet.name = "New Territory"
                DistMaster.Sheets(Territory).Activate
                Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End If

            Dim WS As Worksheet, SheetXXX As Worksheet
            Set WS = WBMaster.Sheets("ReptTemplate")
            WS.Copy after:=Sheets(WBMaster.Sheets.Count)

            Set SheetXXX = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
            SheetXXX.name = Worksheets("ReptTemplate").Range("A1").Value
            CurDstTerrFile.Close

        Loop

        Dim DistWS As Worksheet
        Dim DistName As String
        Dim wbNew As Workbook

        DistName = Left(DistrictDSM, 6) & "*"
        Set wbNew = Application.Workbooks.Add

        For Each DistWS In WBMaster.Sheets
            If DistWS.name Like DistName Then DistWS.Move after:=Sheets(wbNew.Sheets.Count)
        Next DistWS

        With wbNew
            .SaveAs "H:\Accounting\Monthend " & YYYY & "\DSM Files\DSM Master Reports\" & DistrictDSM & ".xlsx"
            .Close
        End With

    Next DistrictDSM

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: without really diving into this, at the bottom of the code you need to set `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` to reset when you changed it at the start

Comment: The code after `If wsExists = False Then` is always going to run because you never attempt to set it to `True` anywhere else in your code - what purpose does `wsExists` even serve? You just set it to `False` at the start and never touch it again.

Comment: Also what is the value of `wsCount` when your `For` statement starts? What is the value of `Territory`?

Comment: Good point regarding `If wsExists = False Then`. I was attempting to cobble this code together based on something found on the Internet to do what I needed.  I believe I need to set it equal to `True` initially based on whether a Territory in the monthly file has a matching Territory worksheet exists in the Master workbook.  `wsCount` = 9 when the `For` statement starts as there are 8 Territory worksheets plus 1 Summary worksheet in the master wkbk.  `Territory` = `Atlanta 01` initially, which is what I expected.

Comment: I'm still stuck if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: unrelated to the solution - I'm curious about this line :   `CurDstTerrFile.Sheets("Index").Range("S20").Copy 'VR` Specifically, the range S20.  Every other segment that precedes and follows use an identical pattern, but this one doesn't.  If it used the same pattern as the others then the range would have been R20.  What changed in the workbook to cause this?

Comment: I'm not suggesting you refactor your code but in the future, on a different project, you would likely benefit by using variables to allow the reusing of code instead of repeatedly typing with slightly different hard coded values.  You may find your programs get shorter,  easier to read, and faster to debug.  for example, inside the for x loop, you have at least 20 lines of code and what must be more than 800 chars  that could be made closer to 6 lines with less than 100 characters and be easier to confirm error free.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry but I cannot comment (not enough reputation to comment on questions) or otherwise I would have asked a few question before posting this.

From what I understood. What you need is a logic/algorithm that checks whether a new sheet (new territory) is required be added to the master file before starting the copying process to the master file. If a sheet needs to be added, it should be added at the end of the master file.

The code below is a general code, but you should be able to tweak it easily to fit your purpose. The code below compares the worksheets in *wb2* with *wb1*. if a sheet name in *wb2* does not exist in *wb1* it will be added to a new sheet at the end of *wb1* with a name similar to the one in *wb2*.

This code should be placed immediately after both files are opened.

```
Sub Comapre_Sheets()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim wks1 As Worksheet
Dim wks2 As Worksheet
Dim bWorkSheet_Found As Boolean

Set wb1 = Workbooks("Book1") ''' Change this to the master file
Set wb2 = Workbooks("Book2") ''' Change this to the file that might have the new sheet/territory 

For Each wks2 In wb2.Worksheets

    bWorkSheet_Found = False

    For Each wks1 In wb1.Worksheets

        If wks1.name = wks2.name Then
            bWorkSheet_Found = True
        End If

    Next wks1

    If Not bWorkSheet_Found Then
        wb1.Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(wb1.Sheets.Count)).name = wks2.name
    End If

Next wks2

End Sub
```

Hope this helps you